# Use Spring Boot resource mapping together if a global request mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently trying to set up a Spring Boot MVC app together with React JS. For this reason I've added an easy frontend controller which listens to `**` and serves the index file (builded react js html file).

That's the code:

```java
@Controller
public class FrontendController {

    @GetMapping("**")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

In my webconfig class I have the following resource handlers to make sure all js, img and css files which are accessed by the react js html file through `/static/...`:

```java
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
            "/static/**",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "manifest.json"
        )
            .addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/static/static/",
                "classpath:/static/favicon.ico",
                "classpath:/static/manifest.json"
            );
    }
```

The problem is now that the GET mapping of my frontend controller is overwriting my resource handler. So that if I try to access a resource file like the main JS file (`/static/js/main.js`) the index html document will be served.

I'm not very experienced in Spring Boot and how these components work together but is there a way to prioritize the resources? Or how can I achieve that if the resource will be server in case of a match with `/static/...`.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

by using this

```
 @GetMapping("**")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

in your controller you're telling it that whatever the url is return index
why not give the index some specific url like "/home"

Comment: That's because I'm serving a React JS application and in this case every request needs to go to the generated `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a little bit of care, because as you know you're making very broad routing rules, but add this to your FrontendController and you will probably get what you're looking for:

`@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)`

This tells Spring to match only when the request has `Accept: text/html`, which is what the browser will send when it's looking for the HTML page.